# Transmission-daemon "settings.json" doesn't work

Tags: raspbian, transmission

I stop the daemon with:

```
/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop
```

after I open with nano the settings (`/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`), and change the value from `"rpc-port": 9091,` to `"rpc-port": 10001,`, save, and start the daemon with:

```
/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon start
```

but nothing ! Doesn't work.

How ? What's wrong ?

I used the `reload` command, but nothing

Comment: If you modified the file when it was stopped, and it still didn't work, it probably was using another file. Search for other `transmission-daemon` directories. Mine just now was using `/home/ubuntu/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of stoping the daemon, just start it, edit the file, and use `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon reload`.

I also suggest you use `sudo`/`su` to edit your file if you're not logged in as root. The full command would be: `sudo nano /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`. It will ask for your password.

Answer (score -1):

Set `chmod 777` for `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`.